# Trouble with PrivateGPT when using 'PGPT_PROFILES=local make run' command

Tags: privategpt

I have been exploring [PrivateGPT](https://github.com/imartinez/privateGPT), and now I'm encountering an issue with my PrivateGPT local server, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving it. When I execute the command **PGPT_PROFILES=local make run**, I receive an unhandled error, but I'm uncertain about the root cause. It appears that this error is somehow connected to my GPU.

I've been following the instructions in the official PrivateGPT setup guide, which you can find here: [PrivateGPT Installation and Settings](https://docs.privategpt.dev/#section/Installation-and-Settings).

While running the command `PGPT_PROFILES=local make run` I got the following errors

```
OSError: libcufft.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

```
    raise ValueError(f"{lib_name} not found in the system path {sys.path}")
ValueError: libcublas.so.*[0-9] not found in the system path ['/home/bennison/Documents/yavar-poc/privateGPT', '/home/bennison/.pyenv/versions/3.11.6/lib/python311.zip', '/home/bennison/.pyenv/versions/3.11.6/lib/python3.11', '/home/bennison/.pyenv/versions/3.11.6/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/home/bennison/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/private-gpt-edPgKWgS-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages', '/home/bennison/Documents/yavar-poc/privateGPT']
```

**System Configurations**
Operating System (OS): Ubuntu 20.04
CPU: 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz (It has 4 cores)
GPU: NV137 / Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
RAM: 16GB
Python Version: 3.11.6

I'm asking for help to figure out why I'm getting this error and how to fix it. Any advice or suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Make sure you have a question about _writing_ software, as opposed to _running_ it -- and paste your logs as text, not screenshots; see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) to understand why screenshots don't count towards meeting [mre] requirements.

Comment: In general, though, this looks like you haven't installed the full set (or the correct version) of nvidia's CUDA libraries. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html is a decent place to start.

Comment: BTW, note that CUDA 11.0 didn't exist until the very end of 2020; it's thus not reasonable to expect a distro from that year to ship with those libraries; you thus need to depend on an external entity (like nvidia) to ship packages.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is it possible to use PrivateGPT's default LLM (mistral-7b-instruct-v0.1.Q4_K_M.gguf) without GPU support, essentially without CUDA?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your help. I've run PrivateGPT on my local machine now. Thanks for pointing out the potential issue with CUDA.

Comment: @donnadulcinea I've successfully addressed this issue, which is connected to CUDA. I've written an article on Medium detailing the steps to resolve it. Please check out my article for the solution:
Link to Article: https://medium.com/@bennisondevadoss/resolving-challenges-while-setting-up-privategpt-on-local-ubuntu-fa0ab65db194

Comment: @BennisonJ I hope you will read this. Please put your article link as the answer. It helped me to solve the issue. I spent almost one hour of trial and catch, but I was able to succeed only because of your guide. Since there is no comment section on medium I add that there is a typo (*-dkpg --> dkpg), and since I didn't find the .so libs anyway after the deb install, I used: `apt install libcudnn8 libcudnn8-dev` and `apt install libnccl2 libnccl-dev`.

Thank you. And sorry that Stack Overflow became a joke.

Comment: @donnadulcinea Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I've made the necessary correction to the typo and included the required 'apt-install' command for the <packages> in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sorted out the issues, and they all revolve around Nvidia CUDA.
You might encounter three consecutive problems:

1. libcublas.so.*[0–9] not found,
2. libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file, and
3. libcudnn.so.2: cannot open shared object file.

I've detailed the solutions in a Medium article. If you're in need of help, please refer to my article for the solutions.
[Medium Article](https://medium.com/@bennisondevadoss/resolving-challenges-while-setting-up-privategpt-on-local-ubuntu-fa0ab65db194)

Answer (score 0):

### Python Version:

3.11    -- https://python.org/downloads.

### Download Repository:

git clone https://github.com/imartinez/privateGPT.git

cd privateGPT

### Install Dependencies:

pip install poetry

poetry install --extras "ui llms-llama-cpp embeddings-huggingface vector-stores-qdrant"

poetry run python scripts\setup

ollama serve

(in other terminal):
make run

- open your web browser and navigate to 127.0.0.1:8001